# Pandas create graph from Date and Time while them being in different columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, graph

My data looks like this:

```
     Creation Day      Time St1       Time St2
0    28.01.2022        14:18:00       15:12:00
1    28.01.2022        14:35:00       16:01:00
2    29.01.2022        00:07:00       03:04:00
3    30.01.2022        17:03:00       22:12:00
```

It represents parts being at a given station. What I now need is something that counts how many Columns have the same Day and Hour e.g. How many parts were at the same station for a given Hour.
Here 2 Where at Station 1 for the 28th and the timespan 14-15.

Because in the end I want a bar graph that show production speed. Additionally later in the project I want to highlight Parts that havent moved for >2hrs.

Is it practical to create a datetime object for every Station (I have 5 in total)? Or is there a much simpler way to do this?

FYI I import this data from an excel sheet

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As they are just strings I can just add them and reformat the result with `pd.to_datetime()`.

Example:

```
df["Time St1"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Creation Day"] + ' ' + df["Time St1"],
    infer_datetime_format=False, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'
)
```